# How to add new country in country dropdown in magento2.2.1

Tags: magento2.2, country-regions

I want to add new country and its region in magento2.2.1 so it can be shown throughout the site(including backend countried dropdown, checkout at frontend).

I have tried this link of magento1 but did not worked in M2-
http://snipplr.com/view/56229/add-new-country-to-magento/

Can anyone help me ?

**EDIT--**

I want to add "Channel Islands" as new country and I couldn't found its ISO2 and ISO3 code.

Comment: You want to add  country  or region?

Comment: I am trying to add new country in Magento Default Country dropdwon however our changes are not getting reflected on server. I am using Magento **2.2.2** & I followed below steps to add new country. However its not working with my Magento version. 1. Open `lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml` 2. Locate territories tag in this file 3. copy one of territory tags for the syntax and paste it within the territories tag 4. hard part here is to add country code in this file as might not be able to find a unique one, so it’s upto you. 5. Save this file 6. Open table name directory_country 7. It has predefined

Answer (score 2):

> Step1: Open lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml
>
> Step2: Locate territories tag in this file
>
> Step3: copy one of territory tags for the syntax and paste it within
>   the territories tag
>
> Step4: hard part here is to add country code in this file as might not
>   be able to find a unique one, so it’s upto you.
>
> Step5: Save this file
>
> Step6: Open table name directory_country
>
> Step7: It has predefined syntax follow then same and create a new row
>   and enter the same country code as entered in the en.xml file in 3
>   columns
>
> Step8: Refresh the site’s cache.
>
> Step9: Admin > Configuration > General

- https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/How-to-add-new-country-on-Magento-2-1-1/m-p/69286/highlight/true#M2943

Comment: but magento doesn't have `lib/zend` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below link and it helps me to add a new country

[Add new nation into nation's list in Magento 2.3.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330838/add-new-nation-into-nations-list-in-magento-2-3-5/330897#330897)